# Quick inquiry about dict mapping

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

How can I map single or multiple things to a single element in a dictionary in python.

For example:

```
dict of str: {str: [str, int]}
```

Comment: What you have there will work fine. `foo = {'bar': ['baz', 1, 'foobar']}`

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = dict()
myDict["myString"] = ["myList", 1, 0.0]
print myDict
```

**Output**

```
{'myString': ['myList', 1, 0.0]}
```

Example from http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

You can create `dict` in python in the following ways

```
>>> a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
>>> b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
>>> c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
>>> d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
>>> e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
>>> a == b == c == d == e
True
```

You can use a list instead of any of the values (`1, 2 or 3`)

Comment: and its amazing how many different ways python has of creating dictionaries... they all must have their importance in specific instances..

Comment: @user2954367 What did you try? Please update the question with the code you have.